# Updating depreacted jwt-function with custom JwtAuthenticationConverter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have this line of code:

```
http.oauth2ResourceServer(server -> server.jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter()));
```

with

```
@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
...
}
```

jwt() is deprecated and I'm tried to use `jwt(JwtConfigurer)`. How does that work? How to register my AuthenticationConverter with that function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#webflux-oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction

```
 http
     .oauth2ResourceServer(configurer ->
            configurer.jwt(
                jwtConfigurer -> jwtConfigurer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter())
            )
     )
```

Comment: Solved the problem. Thanks.